# Swift : literals implicit type casting

Tags: swift

Suppose I have the following snippet

```
let x = 3
let y = 0.5
let z = x + y
let z1 = 3 + 0.5
```

For declaring `z` obviously I get an error :
"binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'
let z = x + y"

But `z1` is fine. Is there an implicit type casting for literals?

Comment: Please read [Type Safety and Type Inference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID322) in the Language Guide

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me out - now it's clear that here I get Type Inference and this code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you declare in let x = 3 and let y = 0.5 two types. One is the type of an integer and one is the type of a double. Literals are not a type, they are literals. The type is inferred at let z1 = 3 + 0.5, which is 3.5 and therefore z1 is inferred to be a double. Swift doesn't typecast a literal, it typecasts a type.